# Spring: inject byte array into ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, byte, arrays, inject

what is the correct way of injecting a byte array into an arraylist?

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> bytes;

<property name="bytes">
<list>
    <value>0x03,0x4d</value>
</list>
</property>
```

does not work, as every character (0,x,0,3) is converted into a single byte.
I also tried encoding like &#03;, but that doesn't work either.

One workaround would be converting to integer first an then manually convert back to byte in the bean, but that is not too pretty.

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in `ByteArrayPropertyEditor`, but according to the Javadoc, it only converts Strings into corresponding byte array:

> Editor for byte arrays. Strings will simply be converted to their corresponding byte representations.

Maybe you should [write your own](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) property editor to convert arbitrary representation of `byte[]` into list?

Comment: "it only converts Strings into corresponding byte array"
Thats the problem, cause I don't know how to type STX (0x03h) as a string ;)

Comment: You can't as you have UTF-8 encoded XML file and while it works for strings with national characters (e.g. Chinese), you can't use arbitrary bytes. That's why I suggest you to write custom property editor that will, for example, read Base64 encoded strings and convert them to bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a FactoryBean to create your byte array:

```
public class ByteArrayFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<byte[]>{

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType(){
        return byte[].class;
    }

    private String data;

    @Required
    public void setData(final String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] createInstance() throws Exception{
        final String[] tokens = data.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        final byte[] output = new byte[tokens.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
            output[i] = Byte.decode(tokens[i]).byteValue();
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
<bean class="foo.bar.SomeBean">
    <property name="bytes">
        <list>
            <bean class="foo.bar.ByteArrayFactoryBean">
                <property name="data" value="0x03,0x4d" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(Registering a `PropertyEditor` would be more correct, but also more work)

---

But if I understand your comments right, your actual problem is that you don't know how to write a String with exotic bytes? You can use [Unicode escapes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#48089):

```
System.out.println("H\u00e4\u00e4\u00e4\u00e4\u00e4hhh???");
```

Output:

> Hääääähhh???

You can of course also use this syntax in Spring XML files.

Comment: Using <value>\u0003</value> will result in a byte array containing [92, 117, 48, 48, 48, 51], instead of 0x03h. 92 is the value for "\", 117 for "u" etc.